# How can I make the button be black and white with round edges?

Tags: magento2, layout, code, custom-button

Banners have the correct button I want, black with white text and rounded edges
[image: correct button]

The buttons added to the page have a burgundy boarder and blue text [image: wrong button]

Can someone help as I cant find this anywhere in the code. I just want it to be like the banner buttons

```
<style>
/* DEV NOTE: THESE STYLES ARE NOT SUITABLE FOR THE REST OF THE SITE */
#maincontent {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}

@media (min-width: 1366px) {

#maincontent {
  padding-top: 1.4rem;
}

}

.breadcrumbs {
  display: none;
}

.cms-page-view h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.7rem;
}

[data-appearance='collage-centered'] .pagebuilder-banner-wrapper .pagebuilder-overlay {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: static;
}

.banner-main .pagebuilder-banner-wrapper .pagebuilder-overlay {
  margin-bottom: 4.8rem;
}

.pagebuilder-banner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  background-position: center !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {

.cms-page-view h1 {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.pagebuilder-banner-wrapper {
  min-height: 310px !important;
}

[data-appearance='collage-centered'] .pagebuilder-banner-wrapper .pagebuilder-overlay {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.banner-main .pagebuilder-banner-wrapper .pagebuilder-overlay {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

}

@media (max-width: 1365.98px) {

[data-content-type=row][data-appearance=contained] [data-element=inner] {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

}

button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary {
  background: #000000;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: 'Rift', Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5rem 3.2rem;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary::before {content: '';position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;background-color: #baa8ce;z-index: -1;opacity: 0;transition: all .2s linear;}

button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.pagebuilder-overlay h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.7rem;
}

.pagebuilder-overlay p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.pill-list {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 1.5rem !important;
}

.pill-list h3 {/* font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif !important; */font-size: 2.4rem;margin-top: 1rem;margin-bottom: 3rem;}

.pill-list ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.pill-list li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.pill-list ul a {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  border: 1px solid rgba(51,51,51,.2);
  border-radius: 99px;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 1.05rem 3.9rem;
  margin: 0.3rem 0.3rem 1rem;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

.pill-list ul a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pagebuilder-column:not(:only-child) .widget .products-grid ol.products.list.items.product-items li.item.product.product-item {
  width: 50%;
}

.pagebuilder-column:not(:only-child) .widget .products-grid ol.products.list.items.product-items {
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pill-list li {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.pagebuilder-column figure {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.pagebuilder-column figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
.pill-list ul a {
  padding: 0.75rem 2.75rem;
}
}

@media (max-width: 360.98px) {
.pill-list li, .pill-list a {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 667px) and (max-width: 849px) {

.pagebuilder-column:not(:only-child) .widget .products-grid ol.products.list.items.product-items li.item.product.product-item {
  width: 50% !important;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try this code in any online editor to give you an idea, so you will understand easily.

you can try some thing like this

Button HTML

```
<div id=a>BUY NOW</div>
```

And, CSS

```
div#a {
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    background: black;
    color:white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;

    /* Prevent background color leak outs */
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; 
    -moz-background-clip:    padding; 
    background-clip:padding-box;
}
```

It should be look like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to apply the same stylings from this part to all buttons.

```
button.pagebuilder-banner-button.pagebuilder-button-primary {
  background: #000000;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-family: 'Rift', Roboto, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding: 1.5rem 3.2rem;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

The buttons in general have different stylings, min "primary" and "secondary". So if you want to modify all pagebuilder primary buttons you could use a css selector like

```
button.pagebuilder-button-primary { your styles }
```

This would then also effect the banner buttons so you can just remove ‘.pagebuilder-banner-button‘ from the code you already have and it possibly works.

Depending which theme youre using, like you you use Luma theme, it might be best to modify the button style variables instead of adding css code. Here is a good post about where you can make such changes https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-customize-themes-styles-in-magento/